# Spreading tuples and also applying optional attributes

Tags: typescript

Can the code below be modified, such that `Test2` produces: `[string, boolean?, ...string[]]` by factoring in the optional field?

```js
type Def = { type: any, spread: boolean, optional: boolean }
type A = { type: string,   spread: false, optional: false }
type B = { type: boolean,  spread: false, optional: true  }
type C = { type: string[], spread: true,  optional: false }
type D = { type: number,   spread: false, optional: false }

type ArrayBuilder<
  T extends Def[],
  A extends any[] = [],
  B extends any[] = [],
  C extends any[] = [],
  State extends 'A' | 'B' = 'A',
> = T extends [
  infer H extends Def,
  ...infer R extends Def[],
] ? State extends 'A' ? H['spread'] extends true ? ArrayBuilder<R, A, H['type'], [], 'B'> : ArrayBuilder<R, [...A, H['type']], [], [], 'A'>
  :ArrayBuilder<R, A, B, [...C, H['type']], 'B'>
  : [...A, ...B, ...C]

type Test1 = ArrayBuilder<[A,C,D]> // [string, ...string[], number]

// Can the code above be modified, such that Test2 produces: [string, boolean?, ...string[]] by factoring in the optional field?
type Test2 = ArrayBuilder<[A,B,C]> // [string, boolean, ...string[]] - should become [string, boolean?, ...string[]]
```

To apply the spread, I'm doing `[...A,...ItemToSpread]`, but to apply the optional attribute I must do `{[I in keyof T]?: T[I] }` - which doesn't play nice with spreads.

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmUC8UDeVSQFxQIYDsQAaKAZzACcJcATHAIwHtGAba-ExsYAS0f1wsGzNgSgBfAFCZoAQWRoM4CDlLAKPfAHMSUMpWp0o8QaQidufAUOOnoUmVABCC9DOGt2u8lVo4TLGYWvPyCOOoArtAS0spQAMKuSthk6ppaANoAuiQ+huEUUbpcIdb+djGOMEnuUPgRALb0EBS6+r5GAUFQJVZhtoH2krGQULIUFLggThE8LDQtADySegAqUBAAHsAQ+DSksAjZRCtjG9u7+3iE2QrHpy5bO3sHBCC3KPd6iU+XrzdZO45U4AZWAuB252eVwA5LIYVAAD5QGFOBEoOEwk4APgU61+LygGVOmngLSgAAkoX9DvATnoAHRM0nkgBK1MJcHg90BAH4oGCIdACbD4VB+RSMjC8rQYYCRQdItB+eNJtNZvMlqySLISJKYTI5SRjii0bicKqpjM5gsKIttUSmQzdZSpYasjkiZ6TZjsacsJb1TatTqSE5jU74nq3co5Z7UTC-XocBknS6neGoJGssNHKsIGoAIwKQPWzV2jK6qMwLK4gD0daJag02hITub6RN9SaLRzkgbCTEwAAFtAAMaMBZ4JgAN2gzSgDUnPHgPAgNFyETHw4ww4hUHzagATFBKJOtwWUx3W1AmJ4CLy20zr5kPbeQLYx8BGC2tFBNLu0C9KELDGGu8y8iM0CHsAJ4oKWGq2oslZEOG8S1lAA4ZC+JB3qIHBZs+aTaNkgIALRkMOjARPMt4QBODTQNhxE6LeIjsI+hEMi+pHDMMQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you check for `H["spread"]`, you can check for `H["optional"]` before passing `H["type"]` to `ArrayBuilder`:

```
type ArrayBuilder<
  T extends Def[],
  A extends any[] = [],
  B extends any[] = [],
  C extends any[] = [],
  State extends "A" | "B" = "A"
> = T extends [infer H extends Def, ...infer R extends Def[]]
  ? State extends "A"
    ? H["spread"] extends true
      ? ArrayBuilder<R, A, H["type"], [], "B">
      : H["optional"] extends true ? ArrayBuilder<R, [...A, H["type"]?], [], [], "A"> : ArrayBuilder<R, [...A, H["type"]], [], [], "A">
    : H["optional"] extends true ? ArrayBuilder<R, A, B, [...C, H["type"]?], "B"> : ArrayBuilder<R, A, B, [...C, H["type"]], "B">
  : [...A, ...B, ...C];
```

and if you have [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) enabled, you will get the desired result for `Test2`:

```
type Test2 = ArrayBuilder<[A, B, C]>; // [string, boolean?, ...string[]]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmUC8UDeVSQFxQIYDsQBuKAZzACcJcATHAIwHtGAba-ExsYAS0f1wsGzNgSgBfIgChM0AILI0GcBBylgFHvgDmJclVo54g0hE7c+AoVGMtTE6bKgAhRelnDW7PZWp0bJmZQXLz8gjgaAK7QkjIqUADCbsrYZBpa2gDaALo+Bv5RQSGW4QF2MY7xMMkeUPiRALb0EBR5fkaB5qFWHeUOUnGQUHIUFLggzpE8LDQtADxSUFAAKlAQAB7AEPg0pLAIOQA0i8Nrm9u7eIQ5ikcnrhtbO3sEIDcod0tJjxcv19m3bLHJYAZWAuC2ZyelwARHIYVAAD5QGHOBEoOEwqQAPkUqx+zygmS08BaUAAElDfvt4IcoAA6RkkskAJSphLg8By2ROAH4oGCIdACbD4SclvzyZkYfo-DCASK9oVxUsoPyRmMJlMZvMWXS5HSpTDZPK6UcUWjsSqljgjcUwix5ezLoU1cNRuNJtNZhQ5nqiYz6QaKdKTdleUCiZHzZjcTgNZ7tT6-WbA8GjWHo1m6bGVbbpfarE7FRgKNE3Qmtd7dfq6c5U4yEobQyp5RGc5aoPGPVWdb7-cH6wHG83ja3spHUTCrTbh0G6YGh4GErkBk4AGJzZa4lDoTIAaSgWigAGsICBGIhltkcABRdYAYxYkVmW4PkciOwQWggNFx4jXeJlggdQAEZFErL0+zmTJgybWBsmxEgAHpkKJdRNB0BdGQwjJzXqJoWh5QZoGA9QACYIJ7KDk1gus6RXJCoFQ9D0iwqAmC8AheWw+lcJ0bkgA)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know one could do `H["type"]?` - kinda obvious now in hindsight.